# C++: MD5 Value of uploaded file on Azure

Tags: c++, azure, blob, md5

I've seen the example from Azure [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blobs/samples/transactional_checksum.cpp) and you can see that when uploading a data it uses stream and also provides md5 hash of that stream.

My main purpose is to upload file into azure and provide md5, if local md5 and one calculated by Azure doesn't match it will return an error.

I also know that I can use `uploadFrom` function which takes a filename and opens it and takes care of the "chunking" etc. The main problem is that it doesn't allow me to specify md5 hash as it does in `upload` case. `uploadFrom` accepts different type of `options` structure which doesn't have `TransactionalContentHash` member.

Is there any functionality in Azure which would allow me to send a file and provide md5? I know I can open it and read chunks and calculate md5 and send them one-by-one but I want to avoid that headache if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do. If you want to do an online checksum calculator, it's not worth it.

If you want that, the simplest way is probably adding 2 uploads: one of the file (data) and one of a checksum file (the "control" file), with input validation, of course, then proceed from there, where you calculate the md5 and check the control file.

If you want to create a repository for another business process, then it's a different story. In fairness, what you described is not how designing a validation flow works at all. You don't ask a client for data, their version of a checksum, then you check the data and validate if the two checksums are identical. The reason behind this is simple: a server *should never ever* trust a client.

Imagine this scenario: There is data. It can be a file or transient data, it's irrelevant. I edited it (again, the purpose is irrelevant, I can do it to sabotage, for fun or because I am infecting the data with malware), I know the new checksum is incorrect and I know you will catch that. So what I do is I send you the altered file and the new checksum, not the one that the file had before I edited it. Now you check the data and see the checksums are identical. You tell me "thank you sir, you are honest and did not modify anything". But I did, and I lied, didn't I ? :)

The real flow of a validation approach is this:

1. The client agreed what data should be sent upon beforehand, therefore you have a list of the valid checksums
2. The client sends data that to the server
3. The server calculates the checksum and sees if it's identical
4. If it isn't, it rejects the data, if it is, it moves to the next step

Now I know there are sites where they give you files and their checksum in a separate file, but that is the reversed flow: server to client. In theory, a client *could* trust a server.

There is an approach, though, that works in a way that is similar to the one you describe: the client sends data to the server (or a centralized services that would distribute the data to other clients) and also sends a sort of a checksum and the server uses that to validate that nobody changed it along the way (such as MITM attacks).

In that case you should consider a secure transmission (look up HTTPS and TLS) and digital signatures (also look up certificates public+private keys). While this paradigm is usually used for web services, not file uploads, it can be done if the file is packaged after being encrypted by an app client-side (for example in a p7s file). For that you need a key exchange between your server and the client.

Small caveat: MD5 is not secure. Don't rely on it for sensitive data.